# Modify shared state and notify std::condition_variable if std::mutex::lock throws

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I encountered some problem and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable CV;
std::mutex m;
std::size_t i{0};

void set_value() try
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{2});
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m};
        i = 20;
    }
    CV.notify_one();
}
catch(...){
    //what to do?
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t{set_value};
    t.detach();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m};
    CV.wait(lock, []{ return i != 0; });

    std::cout << "i has changed to " << i << std::endl; 
}
```

This of course works fine but how should I handle the case when `std::lock_guard::lock` throws an exception?

At first I was thinking to create global `std::atomic<bool> mutex_lock_throwed{ false };` that I could set to `true` inside the `catch` block. Than I could notify_one()

```
catch(...){
    mutex_lock_throwed.store(true);
    CV.notify_one();
}
```

and change predicate for `wait` function to

```
[]{ return i != 0 || mutex_lock_throwed.load(); }
```

This actually worked very well but I read this in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

As you can see its not possible if `mutex` throws. So what should be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: if lock_guard couldn't lock the mutex, it's likely that cv.wait won't be able to either, and when cv.wait can't lock, it terminates. It may be worth using another notification mechanism if you need to be that robust.

Comment: One question to ask would be, why would the lock_guard throw an exception?  If it's something that's only likely to happen in unrecoverable circumstances (e.g. due to a bug in your program), then probably the best thing to do is either let the exception go unhandled so it will crash your program (so that you can debug it more easily), or catch the exception, log an error, and then terminate the program.

Comment: Thank you very much guys :)